# Storm Deployment with AWS CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, apache-storm, aws-code-deploy

I want to use AWS tools for my CI/CD use case. I want to deploy my storm topology on EC2 instances. I am using AWS CodeDeploy for the deployment. I am not able to figure out the following:
1. Before deployment I want to check if Storm is there on the EC2 instance or not.
2. If not then install Storm on given EC2 instances that will form my cluster.
3. Then Deploy my executable jar as a topology on storm.

I know I can define hooks for BeforeInstall step. But I am not able to figure out the script for the above task.